# Azure: equivalent of a several SQS subscribed to a SNS

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

In an application, after some specific event, I want to notify different services via bus service.
With AWS, I would do an SNS and for each service to be notified, I would create an SQS subscribed to the SNS in order to have a specific queue for each service. It allows you to manage deadletters and to replay messages for each recipient service.

For exemple, if a SNS has 2 subscribers : SQS A and SQS B, which are consumed by 2 services, A et B.
If a message is sent to the SNS, the 2 SQS receive the message. A integrate it correclty, but B don't. I will be able to manage it only with the B SQS.
How do I achieve the equivalent with Azure?
I know there is Azure Service Bus, which seem to be the equivalent of the SNS and Queue Storage is an equivalent to the SQS, can I achieve what I want with the 2 by create an Azure Service Bus and 2 queue Storage (one for A and one for B) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at **Azure Service Bus Topics and Subscriptions**. Here, when a message is sent to a Topic, it is broadcasted to one or more Subscriptions based on the filtering rules.

You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions.

Comment: ok i understand why I was confused. I first read somewhere than Azure Service Bus is the equivalent of AWS SNS. That is why I wanted to combined Service Bus with Queue storage. 
But now I get it, as AWS SNS is "just" a notification system (with subscription), Azure Service bus is more complete as every subscription behave like a queue.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two options.

1. For internal (enterprise) systems, [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) is likely sufficient.
2. For internal and external systems, [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) is a strong candidate.

There are additional reasons to go with one over another, but it depends on the scenario. Not to mention that the to can be combined.